# docker-compose equivalent for docker run arguments like "--foo bar" in compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given the following `docker run` command:

```
  -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  rancher/rancher:latest \
  --acme-domain <YOUR.DNS.NAME>
```

What is the notation for writing `--acme-domain` in the docker-compose file? I was not able to find this in the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything after the image name in your `docker run` command line is the "command", which gets executed either by the shell or by your `ENTRYPOINT` script.  The equivalent `docker-compose` directive is `command`.  For example:

```
service:
  image: rancher/rancher:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  command: "--acme-domain <YOUR.DNS.NAME>"
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is an important learning that everything behind the run is the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
docker-compose run service_name --acme-domain <example.com>
```

> Runs a one-time command against a service. For example, the following
>   command starts the web service and runs bash as its command.

```
docker-compose run web bash
```

> Commands you use with run start in new containers with configuration
>   defined by that of the service, including volumes, links, and other
>   details. However, there are two important differences.
>
> First, the command passed by run overrides the command defined in the
>   service configuration. For example, if the web service configuration
>   is started with `bash`, then `docker-compose run web python app.py`
>   overrides it with `python app.py`.

[docker-compose-run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

**update:**

As mentioned by @larsks, pass anything to `command` in docker-compose will be treated as an argument, if look into the [dockerfile the entrypoint](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/blob/master/package/entrypoint.sh) is

```
exec tini -- rancher --http-listen-port=80 --https-listen-port=443 --audit-log-path=${AUDIT_LOG_PATH} --audit-level=${AUDIT_LEVEL} --audit-log-maxage=${AUDIT_LOG_MAXAGE} --audit-log-maxbackup=${AUDIT_LOG_MAXBACKUP} --audit-log-maxsize=${AUDIT_LOG_MAXSIZE} "${@}"
```

so  you can follow the @larsks answer or you can try the above without changing in docker-compose, as the entrypoint will process `"${@}"`

Comment: ...but the question was about the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: I thought he just need to the way to pass argument docker-compose run command.